# fallen into infinite loop and don't know how to escape (unity)

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on Unity, and the code seems to be trapped in an infinite loop

```
void Start()
{
    button = false;

    x = 50;

    y = 50;
}
void Update()
{
    transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.back, x * Time.deltaTime);


    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")) 
    {
        if (button == false)
        {
            button = true;
           
        }
        else
        {
            button = false;
                            
        }
        
    }
    while (button == true)
    {
        Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("fire").transform.position;
        transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, y * Time.deltaTime);
        x = 0;
        y = 50;
    }

    while (button == false)
    {
        Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("ice").transform.position;
        transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, x * Time.deltaTime);
        x = 50;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

}

The code is about changing the pivot of an object so that it's somewhat like the game a dance of fire and ice. The problem seems to be the while loop, which creates an infinite loop that prevents me from starting the code.if you know how to solve this problem please help me...

Comment: You don't need to use 'button == true' or 'button == false', just using button by itself is enough (or !button for button == false) - it's a small change but can make your code easier to read/maintain

Answer (score 1):

Your code will set Y to 50 and keep setting Y to 50 repeatedly (thousands of times) until some section of code updates 'button', after which case it will set Y to 0 and X to 50 thousands of times until button is changed again after which it will finally exit the method. You need to be more explicit in your question as to how/when button is changed, but you need to make better exit conditions for your while loops. If you want to test without infinite loops you could do something like

```
if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")) 
    button = !button
if (button)
{
    Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("fire").transform.position;
    transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, y * Time.deltaTime);
    x = 0;
    y = 50;
}
else
{
    Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("ice").transform.position;
    transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, x * Time.deltaTime);
    x = 50;
    y = 0;
}
```

if you do want that code to keep going until button is affected again, you could do something like

```
public async Task StartSpinVector(){
     if (button)
        while(button)
     {
          Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("fire").transform.position;
          transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, y * Time.deltaTime);
          x = 0;
          y = 50;
          await Task.Delay(50);//so we don't go nuts, wait 50 ms before repeating
      }
      else 
         while(!button)
       {
           Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("ice").transform.position;
             transform.RotateAround(pivotPosition, Vector3.back, x * Time.deltaTime);
             x = 50;
             y = 0;
             await Task.Delay(50);//so we don't go nuts, wait 50 ms before repeating
        }
       }
```

and then in your main update code, call (but don't await) this method so your update doesn't go absolutely nuts

```
   private Task updateLoopTask;
   void Update(){
        ...
        updateLoopTask = StartSpinVector();//save the task in case we want to await it later or something
   }
```

or maybe you might want to do something else, if you elaborate on your question we can make more specific answers

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're expecting the value of `button` to update within your `while` blocks and, given that there isn't any external context for the code you've provided, I can't say whether this is a valid expectation or not for the `Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")` control(?). I'm guessing not based on the fact that you're having a problem.

I expect that you need an event handler for `Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")` wherein the value for `button` is set after which your loop(s) would resume.

As an aside, you might want to look more into asynchronous code flows.

Comment: I'm an extreme newb to unity... is it possible for you to explain a bit more for me?